# Why doesn't this JavaScript function remove square brackets one by one?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var asdf = "a[3] > b[5] > c[1]"

function removebracket(){
var newstring = asdf.replace(/\/[^\/]*$/, '')
alert(newstring);
}

<a href="#" onClick="javascript:removebracket();"> remove square brackets one by one </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little explaining of the regex you have:

```
/\/[^\/]*$/
```

The string between the first and the last `/` is the regex

```
\/[^\/]*$
```

Here the `\/` is matching a `/` since the `\` is used for escaping special characters, like `/`.

```
[^\/]
```

Everything between square brackets `[]` will match exactly one character. `^` inside the brackets means it'll match everything except the next char. Hence `[^\/]` will match everything except a `/`.

The `*` matches zero or more of the previous character.

Lastly the `$` matches end of the string or a newline.

Use it with `/foo/bar` and you'll end up with `/foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression doesn't do anything like remove brackets - it looks like it's for removing parts from a path.
This will remove square brackets:

```
var newstring = asdf.replace(/\[|\]/g, '');
```

Comment: actually i need to remove the last square brackets on each iteration